# How to place blank value for number as default?

Tags: java, swing

Consider the following code:

```
public class Quantity extends Number implements Serializable, UnitAware, Immutable, Comparable<Number>
```

And this:

```
private Quantity test1;
private Quantity test2;
```

I have created a table with the values test1 and test2, but cannot figure out a way to put the default as blank. By default it is considering as 0.

How can I leave the test1 and test2 table as blank?

Comment: Use a separate method for rendering the values, when `null`, display `""`. *"I have created a table"* - Do you mean a `JTable`

Comment: So what's rendering the value of `test1` and `test2`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer It is not rendered anywhere, but still it takes 0 in the panel.

Comment: But what's displaying `0`?  The point is, what is a "default" value for a `Number`?  That's not really something `Number` can decide, it's what is displaying the value, so, for instance, if you pass `null`, then that becomes the "default" and anything else is a `Number`...

Comment: Trying to figure what's displaying 0.